# Reading file's columns into array

Tags: c++, arrays

i'm reading file which has some number of columns each line has different number of columns and they are numerical values of different length, and i have fix number of rows (20) how to put each column in to array?

suppose i have data file like following (there is tab between each column)

```
20   30      10
22   10       9       3     40 
60    4
30    200   90
33    320    1        22    4
```

how to put these columns into different array,, that column 1 goes to one arrary and column 2 goes to another. Only column 2 has more than 2 digit values and the rest of columns has 1 or two digit values, and some columns are null too except 1, 2, and 3

```cpp
int main()
{     
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("Ewa.dat");

    int c1[20], c2[20], ... c6[20];

    while(!infile.eof()) { 
        //what will be the code here?
        infile >>lines;
        for(int i = 1; i<=lines; i++) {
            infile >> c1[i];     
            infile >> c2[i];
             .
             .
            infile >> c6 [20]; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @skaffman You probably meant to tag C++ instead of C ?

Comment: i wanted to tag C++ and i did it.. why?

Comment: No, you didn't tag it at all.  Someone else edited and added a C tag and then another person corrected the C tag to C++.

Comment: okay i'm sorry, i forgot to mention, i accept my mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the main idea:

Use a 2D array instead of many 1D arrays.
Read each line using `std::string`.
Then use:     `istringstream is(str);` which will help parse the string and put into the arrays like this:

```
while(...) {
    ....
    getline(infile, str);
    istringstream is(str);
    j=0;
    while(is)
        {
            is >> c[i][j];
        }
    i++;
    ....
    }
```

I'll leave the rest to you.

Comment: thanks very much KingsIndian for your time and help, it was really helpful

Answer (score 1):

It might be easier to take advantage of some of some C++ library classes, like [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream), and [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::vector<int> > allData;

  std::ifstream fin("data.dat");
  std::string line;
  while (std::getline(fin, line)) {      // for each line
    std::vector<int> lineData;           // create a new row
    int val;
    std::istringstream lineStream(line); 
    while (lineStream >> val) {          // for each value in line
      lineData.push_back(val);           // add to the current row
    }
    allData.push_back(lineData);         // add row to allData
  }

  std::cout << "row 0 contains " << allData[0].size() << " columns\n";
  std::cout << "row 0, column 1 is " << allData[0][1] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: can you fix the problem of garbage values, it is also filling the array for which i don't have any value in the data file?